# How to display null value in jsp when controller return a null result?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

i have this controller when factoryPIC could return a null value

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/PLR/AjaxGetPIC", method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public @ResponseBody V_PIC_TRIAL_PMFK ajaxGetPIC( HttpServletRequest request,RedirectAttributes ra, Model model) {

    String docNo = request.getParameter("npdrDocument");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<V_SRF> vsrf =  plrAdapter.getV_SRFDocNo(docNo);
    String docSRF = vsrf.get(0).getPlantCode();

    V_PIC_TRIAL_PMFK factoryPIC = plrAdapter.getPICByPlantCode(docSRF);
    System.out.println("factoryPIC" +new Gson().toJson(factoryPIC));
    model.addAttribute("factoryPIC", factoryPIC);
    System.out.println("vsrf" +new Gson().toJson(vsrf));
    String json = gson.toJson(vsrf); 
    return factoryPIC;
}
```

this is the script i have

```
function factoryPIC(){
$.ajax(
{           
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/MOA2/PLR/AjaxGetPIC/?&npdrDocument="+$("#npdrDocument").val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        if(result == "" || result == null || result == " "){
            $("#factoryPIC").val("---");
            $("#factoryPICName").val("---");
            $("#fLabelName").html("---");
        }else{
            $("#factoryPIC").val(result.username);
            $("#factoryPICName").val(result.name);
            $("#fLabelName").html(result.name);
        }
    }
});
```

}

How do i validate if the return result i got from the controller is null and display string "---" in jsp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
function factoryPIC(){
$.ajax(
{           
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/MOA2/PLR/AjaxGetPIC/?&npdrDocument="+$("#npdrDocument").val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        if(!result){
            $("#factoryPIC").val("---");
            $("#factoryPICName").val("---");
            $("#fLabelName").html("---");
        }else{
            $("#factoryPIC").val(result.username);
            $("#factoryPICName").val(result.name);
            $("#fLabelName").html(result.name);
        }
    }
});
```

You do not need to check multiple condition for `result`, you can just check above mentioned condition.

If you want to check empty string or length then you need to add extra 1 clause in if.

If you're using jQuery then even you can use [trim](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) function to check empty json response. Or you can use javascript's native [length](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/jsref_length_string.asp) function to check json response is empty or not.